# In Xamarin.Form a scrollview nested in a scrollview, scrollview inside Failure in Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Nested `ScrollView` is not working. How to solve it?
It confuses me for a long time

```xml
<ScrollView  x:Name="parentScrollView" Grid.Row="1">
    <StackLayout>
        <AbsoluteLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0,-8,0,0">
            <AbsoluteLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All">
                <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="scrollAbsoluteLayout">
                    <ScrollView x:Name="scrollView">
                        <Label x:Name="contentText" FontSize="20" TextColor="{x:Static local:UIColorConfigs.Compliment_text_color}" Margin="35,10,103,0">
                            <Label.FontFamily>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:String" iOS="segoescb" Android="segoescb.ttf#segoescb" />
                            </Label.FontFamily>
                        </Label>
                    </ScrollView>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </AbsoluteLayout>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: According to https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/scroll-view/ nested ScrollViews should be avoided, regardless OS. The example above seems like a bad design, try to rethink it and follow the official guidelines.

Comment: This should work Horizontally/Vertically on Android, issue is reported here:https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9315

Answer (score 4):

You should never nest a `ScrollView` into a `Scrollview`. It's a very bad practice which usually leads to funny behaviors...

Comment: Yes.Is very bad in Android.But it very well in iOS.How can i make it better in Android Xamarin.?

Comment: It's not a matter of OS, it's a matter of design.

Comment: ScrollView inside ScrollView is well designed on iOS. like usual..
It must be possible on Android, Instagram did it So..